# django:type(int instance) shows long

Tags: python, django, pycharm

```
order = OrderCacheTab.objects.filter(order_id=3001180).first()
print type(order.status)
#order.status=7
》》》》<type 'long'>`
```

1. with DB mysql，the order.status is INT(11)
2. with frame django 1.6.11,   status = models.IntegerField()  #
3. python console showed the right answer:int
4. pycharm run console and degug console shows wrong answer type 'long'

Comment: with terminal shows the wrong answer long too

Answer (score 0):

use code below can fix
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
since django use may replace some package background